# How to properly dispose of an object

Tags: c#, design-patterns, oop, delegates

I am experiencing something weird and have a workaround already, but I don't think I understood it well.

If I call the Method below numerous times within a class:

```
public void Method()
{
 Foo a = new Foo();

 a.Delegate1Handler = ViewSomething();
}
```

If I call Method() multiple times in one instance of the class that it is in... I am reinitializing "a" every time but for some reason `a.Delegate1Handler` is still around from the previous initialization, and therefore ViewSomething() is called again and again and again....

I feel like I am forgetting something critical here?

Foo's guts look like:

```
public delegate void Delegate1(T t);
public Delegate1 Delegate1Handler { get; set; }
```

EDIT: (workaround that I put in is described below, but I still don't understand exactly why it was behaving like this) ->

Initialized "a" and it's delegate1Handler outside of "Method" where **delegate1Handler** only gets initialized once and "a" can again get reinitialized - no problem! (or maybe it is I don't know)

Comment: Can you please post the actual code instead of a dummied down version of it? I doubt the problem is in the code you've posted so far since it shouldn't exhibit the problems you describe.

Comment: Maybe your should post more code, to clarify your weird behavior.  And why you use delegate field instead of public event?

Comment: Ok, I will edit my question with more information tonight.

Comment: Hmm, didn't see that coming.  Familiar with constructors?

Comment: @Hans: I didn't understand what you were getting at. Could you post it as an answer please?

Comment: @Voo: I *really* don't understand the original hangup.  Sounds like it got resolved, nothing got upvoted, you can delete your question.  That would be best.

Comment: @Hans: oh I see where you got confused into thinking that I had my answer. The EDIT I made was simply to show what I had to do differently to get it working. But my original question was why when I reinitialize "a" the "a.Delegate1Handler" was still around from previous initialization... Hope this clears it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.Delegate1Handler = ViewSomething();`

To me, this suggests that `ViewSomething()` is a method that returns a delegate.

`ViewSomething()` would be called every time you run `Method()`

Answer (score 0):

I think @hans was getting at something like this in his comment

```
public void Method()
{
 Foo a = new Foo( ViewSomething );
}

// ...
public class Foo
{
    public Foo( Delegate1 del ) // note: accepting the delegate parameter
    {
        DelegateHandler = del;
    }
}
public delegate void Delegate1(T t);

public Delegate1 Delegate1Handler { get; set; }
```